# Javascript Objects & Properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm working through the js track on Codecademy. This exercise asks for the creation of an object within an object, then add the name and number properties to the specific friend object. I keep getting a syntax error upon submission. Can anyone explain where my error is or what I'm not understanding? thanks

```
var friends = new Object();

friends.bill = new Object();
bill: {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    number: "203-000-0000"
}

friends.steve = new Object();
steve: {
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "Jobs",
    number: "600-000-0000" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `friends.bill = new Object()` is redundant, and you need to correctly reference the sub-objects.  This should do the trick:

```
var friends = new Object();

friends.bill = {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    number: "203-000-0000"
}
//...
```

Also, you rarely need to actually call `new Object()` to construct an object: there are few reasons that you should prefer that over implicit object creation with curly brackets.  So you could simplify this even further:

```
var friends = 
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Gates",
        number: "203-000-0000"
    },
    //...
}
```

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, thank you. Out of curiosity, implicit object creation seems more condensed and straight forward. Could you give me an example why one would use new Object() then

Comment: @kevingalarza29: I would like to know that as well.